# gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, u-boot

When trying to run `make -j2 -s` as instructed from this guide, I am getting the following error.

> gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Any idea what I have done wrong or what I have missed?

**EDIT**
This is the link to the guide: http://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot

Comment: Does `gcc` give that error when run outside of `make`? Can you run `gcc` on a simple C file with special flags, like this: `gcc -v -v -v -o simple simple.c`, and update your question with the results?

Comment: What distribution are you running? How did you install GCC?

Comment: Debian, with apt-get install gcc

Comment: Ok, i was not able to find this out. I tried reinstalling debian, but that did not help. So I tried installing ubuntu and ran it on there and it worked...

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked a number of times before:

- [Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [gcc error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory when running with non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344106/gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [execvp: No such file or directory](https://superuser.com/questions/396643/execvp-no-such-file-or-directory)

All seem to point at issues with `PATH` or `env` variables such as `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX`.

What does `strace` say?

PS: you have not linked to any guide that you are following.

Comment: With what options should `strace` be run with? When run without any, there is quite a bit of output...